# how to let mat-table observe changes to it's datasource

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I created an angular 6 project with angular cli.

using angular material for the UI

I'm working on some sort of a e-commerce app so I created a cart service with the following code:

```
import {Inject, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { LOCAL_STORAGE, StorageService } from 'ngx-webstorage-service';
import {Product} from './product';
import {CartProduct} from './CartProduct';



const CART_ITEMS = 'cart_items';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CartService {
  cartItems: {};
  constructor(@Inject(LOCAL_STORAGE) private storage: StorageService) {
    if (!this.storage.has(CART_ITEMS)) {
      this.storage.set(CART_ITEMS, []);
      this.cartItems = {};
    } else {
      this.cartItems = this.storage.get(CART_ITEMS);
    }
  }

  public addProduct(product: Product, quantity: number) {
    if (this.cartItems.hasOwnProperty(product.id)) {
      this.cartItems[product.id].quantity += quantity;
    } else {
      const p: CartProduct = new CartProduct();
      p.product = product;
      p.quantity = quantity;
      this.cartItems[product.id] = p;
    }
    this.storage.set(CART_ITEMS, this.cartItems);
  }
  public setProductQuantity(productId: number, quantity: number): boolean {
    if (this.cartItems.hasOwnProperty(productId)) {
      this.cartItems[productId].quantity = quantity;
      this.storage.set(CART_ITEMS, this.cartItems);
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  public clearCart() {
    this.storage.remove(CART_ITEMS);
    this.cartItems = {};
  }

  public getCart() {
    const cartArray = [];
      for (const k of Object.keys(this.cartItems)) {
        cartArray.push(this.cartItems[k]);
      }
      return cartArray;
  }

  public removeProduct(productId: number): boolean {
    if (this.cartItems.hasOwnProperty(productId)) {
      delete this.cartItems[productId];
      this.storage.set(CART_ITEMS, this.cartItems);
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

I implemented a `getCart()` function that converts the object to an array, in order to provide it as a `DataSource` to `mat-table`.

I have a `Cart` component and a `Product` component that interact with the cart service.

the product component has a 'add product' button with quantity to specify. 
so I implemented it with the following code:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Product} from '../product';
import {CartService} from '../cart.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product.component.scss']
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

  public quantity: number;
  @Input() product: Product;
  constructor(private cart: CartService) {
    this.quantity = 1;
  }

  addToCart() {
    this.cart.addProduct(this.product, this.quantity);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

in my Cart component, i created a remove product function

```
removeProduct(productId) {
    this.cart.removeProduct(productId);
    this.cartItems = this.cart.getCart();
  }
```

as you can see here I actually needed to set the `this.cartItems` variable again for the ui refresh to actually work. so here when I remove a product from the cart from that same component that renders the cart,the refresh works.

but when I add a product from the product component, I need to refresh the page in my browser to see the new product added to the cart products list.

how do I notify the `mat-table` component inside my `Cart` component, that the `DataSource` was changed. in my case it was changed by the `Product` component.

thanks

Comment: Using a subject would be a good choice here in my opinion.

Comment: Did you want something like this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xycmug?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcart%2Fcart.module.ts

Comment: @Wingnod - exactly what I need. thank you very much! wanna post it as answer ?

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful :)

Comment: @Wingnod - very! finally I'm not afraid of RXJS anymore! :) your example allowed me not to get lost in rxjs documentation

Comment: Great! It's a really powerful library. If you're having trouble with rxjs documentation, this is what helped me feel more comfortable with the concepts. Good for a read if you're bored. https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subject (both an observer and observable) can be used to emit changes to the cart to subscribers across the application, regardless of hierarchy, as long as they inject the CartService.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xycmug

The on push mechanism is ideal, as you don't have to manually ask for the items, and you only receive emissions when the items themselves change.